# How put form into two td elements?

Tags: html, forms, html-table

Let's assume I have the following structure

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <input type="text" name="name" />
         </td>
         <td>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" />
         </td>
     </tr>
... 
</table>
```

I need to have forms in each row, but because my inputs are in other `<td>` elements, I don't know how to place the `<form>` element (of course I can use `colspan="2"` and put the form into it, but I need to have two other `<td>` elements).

How can I solve this?

UPDATE: I don't want to use Javascript to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution: Use divs instead of tables.

Other solution, create a separate table for each row. That way, you can put each table in a separate form and put the input fields in the td-s, so they will be inside the form too.

Answer (score 2):

Just place the  tags around the table:

```
<form action="...">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</form>
```

This form will "handle" all the input fields inside the table.

Comment: i have form elements in each row(in each <tr> element), as i said :)

Comment: yes, but they belong all to the same form or not? (all input values are going to be processed by the same "action"?)

Comment: no, they are another forms(actions are same, but values are another)

Comment: I'm not sure if you aren't making a simple design error. Are you sure you need more than one <form>? It's no problem to have multiple input fields in one form (it's in fact the common way)

Comment: each row has it's form.Example: when user submits form N1, product_A is added to his cart, and when he submits form N2, product_B. If there is a way to make this in single form, i will be happy to do it :)

Comment: well, normaly for this use case you should only use one form like in my code snippet above. Just like: <form>.. your (table) code goes here</form> tags. And then you add as many <tr>s and <td>s with <input> fields as you like. In the form action you specify the page/script which processes the form input fields, there you have to handle the "add to basket" logic. Depending of how you want to handle that... maybe you have some checkboxes "[x] add" and one submit button, that adds all checked items to the basket.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a table, and in the table cells, create a form, and in the form, create another table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr><td>
                    ....
                </tr></td>
            </table>
        </form>
    </tr></td>
</table>
```

I am pretty sure it is not possible to mix and match inputs in a form if the forms don't follow each other sequentially i.e. "assign" an input to a form.